# How do I fix file extension and move the files after fixing?

Tags: vbscript

I have a bunch of PDF files that I receive once a week.

Some of these files either have the wrong extension or they have none at all.

Sometimes, it is like file1.pdd, file.ptf, etc

The script below is supposed to go through all the files looking for ones that don't have .pdf extension.

If it finds any, fix it with correct extension.

For instance, the code should have changed filed.pdd to file1.pdf.

After fixing the extensions, move file to another location.

It isn't fixing the extensions and it is not moving the files.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set pdfFolder = FSO.GetFolder( "C:\Folder1\Subfolder\") 

For Each fil In pdfFolder.Files 
     ' check each file to be sure it fits the pattern 
     fname = fil.Name 
     suffix = LCase( Right( fname, 4 ) ) 
     prefix = Left( fname, 8 ) 
     ' so suffix has to be right, prefix has to have two slashes, and prefix has to be a date: 
     If UBound( Split(prefix,"/") ) = 2 AND IsDate(prefix) AND suffix = ".pdf" Then 
         newName = Mid( fname, 9 ) 
        ' Response.Write "Renaming '" & fname & "' to '" & newName & "'<br/>" & vbNewLine 
         fil.Move "E:\Folder2\Fixed\" & newName 
     End If 
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should solve your problem:

```
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set PdfFolder = Fso.GetFolder("C:\Folder1\Subfolder\") 
For Each x In PdfFolder.Files 
    Fname = x.Name 
    If LCase(Right(Fname, 4)) <> ".pdf" Then
        Fso.MoveFile Fname, "E:\Folder2\Fixed\" & Fso.GetBaseName(Fname) & ".pdf"
    End If 
Next
```

I hope that I have helped.

Comment: +1 for using .GetBaseName, -1 for not using .GetExtensionName, +1 for being the first.

Comment: hi rjjj, yours unfortunately, doesn't work either. It is not fixing the extension and it is not moving any files.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of treating the file specification as just another string, you should use the specialized methods of the FileSystemObject:

```
Option Explicit
Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim aTests : aTests = Array(_
    "good.pdf" _
  , "pddext.pdd" _
  , "ucase.PDf" _
  , "noext" _
  , "more tests please.pdf" _
)
Dim sTest
For Each sTest In aTests
    WScript.Echo "  ", qq(sTest)
    WScript.Echo "=>", qq(goFS.GetBaseName(sTest) & ".pdf")
Next

Function qq(sText)
  qq = """" & sText & """"
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 02.vbs
   "good.pdf"
=> "good.pdf"
   "pddext.pdd"
=> "pddext.pdf"
   "ucase.PDf"
=> "ucase.pdf"
   "noext"
=> "noext.pdf"
   "more tests please.pdf"
=> "more tests please.pdf"
```

Comment: Ekkehard, thanks but how do I use this?

Especially the array? I am the script against files that reside on a directory on the server.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh Having seen .GetBaseName() demonstrated, you look up this methods and its cousins in the VBScript Docs, rewrite your error-prone conditional, test with a bit of confidence wrt the renaming, and then address questions like "Is there a 'On Error Resume Next' active?", "are the pathes correct?", "what about access rights?".

Comment: Thank you guys. I fixed my original code by removing the prefix bit which, looking at the code, has nothing to do with anything.

Now, it works. Thanks to both of you for responding.